# Working with multiple dependent PhpStorm projects

Tags: phpstorm

My source files are divided into multiple repositories and they are located in different directories. I've created separate PhpStorm projects for each repository. So I'd like the PhpStorm search functions work across some of the projects. How can get this done? How can I mark dependent projects in PhpStorm?

Note: I've tried making the top folder as "Project Root". But that project root contains many other projects which I don't need so it's little bit inefficient from my point of view.

I've used Netbeans and I can do this by going to project properties and setting include path. I found similar option in PhpStorm at `File > Default Settings > Language & Frameworks > PHP`  and set include path. But PhpStorm  search functions/file open doesn't work for the include path.

Or at least how can I open multiple projects in same window.

My PhpStorm info

```
PhpStorm 2016.2.1
Build #PS-162.1889.1, built on August 23, 2016
Licensed to PhpStorm Evaluator
Expiration date: October 10, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b216 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Open your project
2. `Settings/Preferences | Directories`
3. Use `Add Content Root` button and point to a desired folder
4. Once settings are saved -- those newly added Content Root(s) will become part of the project and will be listed as additional nodes in Project View.

Basically -- the main project folder is a Content Root by itself; using the above you are just adding additional folders to the project-- they will be treated in the same way as main Content Root.

Obviously, since those extra folders will become part of this project, ***current project settings will be applied to those folders as well***.

`PHP | Include paths` are for the 3rd party code/libraries which you just use in your project but not edit them.

---

In **PhpStorm 2016.3** (currently in EAP stage) it will be possible to open additional projects as part of the current one. This allows cross-project search/refactoring etc.

Once opened like that .. *such additional projects will use settings from current project -- just like additional Content Roots do* (basically, a bit easier0to-use version of the above). It will NOT work like NetBeans does where you have a "workspace" and can manage multiple projects with separate settings.

Some links:

- Actual ticket with important details: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-15187#comment=27-1590927
- Latest public EAP builds: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program
- Follow PhpStorm's Blog to be notified about new EAP releases and changes made: https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/

---

> I found similar option in PhpStorm at `File > Default Settings > Language & Frameworks > PHP` and set include path.

`Default Settings` affect **future new projects ONLY** -- they do not affect existing projects in any way.

If anything -- it should have been done via just `File | Settings` (Windows/Linux) or `PhpStorm | Preferences` on Mac.

> But PhpStorm search functions/file open doesn't work for the include path.

Not exactly.

They "do not work" because files from such folders are not intended for editing -- they are just for reference purposes. You still can search/open them .. but you have to use additional options (e.g. in `Find in Path` it could be including "Libraries" scope; in `Navigate | File` and similar -- "include non-project files" or so).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Adding content roots seems working. I'll try for few days and accept your answer.

Comment: It has been nearly six years and a full-fledged support for multi-module projects is still not happening. See another ticket for info https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-34158/Support-configuration-of-each-project-in-case-of-multiple-projects-in-the-same-window

Answer (score 9):

Depending on who says it, it is either a **MYTH** or a **LIE** that PHPStorm really **supports** working with multiple projects in the same window.

It allows you to **open** multiple projects in one window, but it doesn't really **support** working with them in any meaningful way.

There is **no way** to indicate **which** of the many opened projects you have in mind whenever you invoke **any** operation that involves the notion of "current project". The "current project" choice is **immutable** for the lifetime of the "workspace": it is precisely **the** first project that was opened/created in it, and there is **no way** to mark any other project as current / active / "the one you have in mind".

**All** supposedly "per-project" configuration settings are in fact the settings of this "main" or "host" project, the first one that was added to the workspace. There is **no way** to configure **anything** *per* any of the further projects that you attached to the workspace later. Those further projects are **not** first-class citizens in the workspace.

This design has been thus broken since the beginning, and there have been FURTHER breakages that exacerbated this problem. For example, PHPUnit run configurations used to have *some* awareness of **the** project **in which** the relevant `phpunit.xml` is located, and it was possible, albeit hackily, to customize some configurables *per* project. This ability has since been removed by developer's **conscious, actively user-hostile decision**.

Answer (score 0):

- You can also ignore files/folders per project too from the `Project Structure` window.

[image: Project Structure window]